# Injecting SQL into a Python String using PyCharm

Tags: sql, pycharm

How do you inject SQL into a Python string and get auto-complete in PyCharm?

Comment: There's still no official support, but there's a support via an [Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485507/pycharm-sql-language-injection-support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL language injection is supported starting with PyCharm 3.0 (it was not supported at the time this question was asked).

The details can be found at [Using Language Injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html).

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

1. *Alt+Enter* on a string -> *Inject language or reference* -> choose needed *SQL*
2. Write a comment in that way:
   [image]