# PyCharm SQL Language Injection support

Tags: sql, sqlite, pycharm, markup

I'm writing some python code with the sqlite3 package. 
I want to put some SQL code into a string literal.
As I found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html), Python supports Injections with markup and coding assistance for several languages, including SQL:

> (such as HTML, CSS, XML, SQL, RegExp, etc.)

Sadly, when I want to try this feature, I found support for several languages like HTML or JQL, but I'm looking for SQL.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215371/injecting-sql-into-a-python-string-using-pycharm), it should be available since Pycharm 3.0.

Is there any way to get SQL Language injections with markup and coding assistance running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem after long search:

Install the plugin [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator).
*(File->Settings->Plugins->Browse repositories->search for Database Navigator)*

This will provide you with support for several SQL dialects including sqlite.
Sadly code-completion features don't support upper-case.

[This is how the SQL support looks like - first line in proper uppercase, second line as with autocomplete-suggestion in lowercase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRW9c.png)

**EDIT:**
I could also solve this problem by changing the language settings for SQL:
*(File->Settings->Editor->CodeStyle->SQL->enable Case, set uppercase where you wish to)*

Answer (score 0):

SQL injections are available only in PyCharm Pro version